# Unchecked Checked Checkbox Always Returning Value

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox

I have 3 HTML checkboxes on an ASP.NET page.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="level-option-1" name="level-option-1" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="level-option-2" name="level-option-2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="level-option-3" name="level-option-3" value="3" />
```

These strings are created server-side and added into the page (by setting the `Text` of a `Literal`). `level-option-1` is checked.

When the page is posted back, `Request.Form["level-option-1"]` has a value of `1` (because the checkbox is checked via the server-side string build). `Request.Form["level-option-2"]` and `Request.Form["level-option-3"]` do not exist (as I would expect).

If `level-option-1` is unchecked (in the browser), and `level-option-2` is checked (in the browser), `Request.Form["level-option-1"]` still has a value of `1` when posted back. `Request.Form["level-option-2"]` has the correct value of `2` and `Request.Form["level-option-3"]` does not exist.

I don't understand how `Request.Form["level-option-1"]` always has a value. I have tried using the XHTML `checked="checked"` also with the same outcome.

If I modify the string build so that the below is generated - `Request.Form["level-option-1"]` only exists with a value of `1` when it has been checked in the browser - which is what I would expect.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="level-option-1" name="level-option-1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="level-option-2" name="level-option-2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="level-option-3" name="level-option-3" value="3" />
```

Assuming the `checked` attribute has been set server-side, how do I know if it is actually checked or not when it's posted back? Is this normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, if it returns a variable (not blank or not null), then it is selected.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.aspx

```
if (Request.Form["checkboxName"] != null && Request.Form["checkboxName"] == "on")
     {
         Response.Write("This checkbox is selected");
     }
     else
     {
         Response.Write("This checkbox is not selected");
     }
```

Comment: This too is my understanding, but not the behaviour I am experiencing :(

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to fully fix this problem, but the solution I ended using was to build the HTML strings (server side) without the `checked` attribute. Then client side, making an AJAX call to determine if they need to be checked or not.

Pretty rubbish really, but then so was the issue ;)